# Say " How to Fix this issue with API Service Call " in TypeScript "?

Tags: typescript

I m tryin to call the API Service and printing its response in the console in the form of object that formed by class with the help of constructor

I m running the Typescript that calls the API Service

```
import * as request from "request";
import { Users } from "./Users";

export class GitubHubApiService{
    getUserInfo(username : String){
   let options : any = {
       headers:{
       "User-Agent" :"request"
    },
    json : true
   }
        request.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+ username ,options,(error:any , Response : any,body: any) => {
            console.log((body));

        let user = new Users((body));
        console.log(user);
        })
    }
}

 This class form the object using those response from API Service call.

export class Users{

    login : String;
    fullName : String;
    repoCount : number;
    followerCount : number;


    constructor(userRes :any){
        this.login = userRes.login;
        this.fullName = userRes.name;
        this.repoCount = userRes.public_repos;
        this.followerCount = userRes.followers;


    }

}
```

Users {
  login: undefined,
  fullName: undefined,
  repoCount: undefined,
  followerCount: undefined }

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You cant assign like this, use getters and setters

```
 import * as request from "request";
    import { Users } from "./Users";

        export class GitubHubApiService{
            getUserInfo(username : String){
           let options : any = {
               headers:{
               "User-Agent" :"request"
            },
            json : true
           }
                request.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+ username ,options,(error:any , Response : any,body: any) => {
                    console.log((body));

                let user = new Users();
                user.data = body;
                console.log(user.data);
                })
            }
        }
```

This class form the object using those response from API Service call using get and set methods

```
    export class Users{

        login : String;
        fullName : String;
        repoCount : number;
        followerCount : number;


        constructor(){

        }
    set data(userRes :any) {
               this.login = userRes.login;
                this.fullName = userRes.name;
                this.repoCount = userRes.public_repos;
                this.followerCount = userRes.followers;

    }
get data() {
return { login: this.login, fullName: this.fullName, repoCount:this.repoCount, followerCount: this.followerCount}
}
```

}

I have a doubt you don't simply use like this

```
 export class GitubHubApiService{
        getUserInfo(username : String){
       let options : any = {
           headers:{
           "User-Agent" :"request"
        },
        json : true
       }
            request.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+ username ,options,(error:any , Response : any,body: any) => {
                console.log((body));
            let user = { login: body.login, fullName: body.name, repoCount: body.public_repos, followerCount:followers }
            console.log(user);
            })
        }
    }
```